# one big image or four images for splash

Tags: android, android-layout

Which solution is good for making a splashScreen?
 1. A large image(Typically it's suitable for `xhdpi` devices) and set `scaleType` to `fitxy` or something else that I don't know,
Or
 2. Make 4 images and put them in 4 folders with these names:
`drawable-ldpi , drawable-mdpi , drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi`?

Or another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it really depends on the type of Splahscreen image that you have. Does it have text? (in which case scaling down might look bad). It also depends on whether you are looking to reducing the size of your *apk* or not.

Personally, I'd rather go with a single Splashscreen in the highest density and let system do  the scaling (then of course don't forget to test it on different devices and see how it looks).

**[EDIT]**

As for the scaleType I don't recommend using FIT_XY given that it doesn't conserve the aspect ratio (will scale your image horizontally but not vertically). FIT_START, FIT_END, FIT_CENTER might not work because they won't fill the screen which is bad for a Splashscreen.

So I think CENTER_CROP might be a good solution, as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) says:

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
>   both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
>   larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Comment: splash image can't nine patchable(even on borders).and undoubted i wanna a apk with Minimum size.for your solution,with one image,should i set scaleType to what?fitCenter?fitXY?Center?...?

Comment: FIT_XY will stretch your image horizontally to the bounds and won't do much vertically. So the ratio won't be kept. I think CENTER_CROP might work well in your case.

Comment: what's Disadvantages of system auto scaling?heap?cpu?time?

Comment: Well in theory it will slow down the app at startup as the system tries to downscale things but should not be an issue with modern devices (might be interesting to test on very old devices). Memory could be an issue too, same thing here might be a problem on very old devices (with little memory budget/VM). Also, Jelly Bean is better at down scaling assets than any other version. So I definitely recommend benchmarking and testing on various devices with different OS versions/resolutions/CPU Power/Memory budget per VM.

Comment: if i have a repeated background and a logo center of screen,is it good solution to use scaleType=fitCenter  OR   Cwenter  OR ... ? exactly what's different between scaleType items?

Comment: Alright I recommend you reading this page: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846580&seqNum=2 There are some screenshots that explains the difference between all scaling types.

Answer (score 0):

you put three resolution image then
XMl use this one android:adjustViewBounds=true
or
coding use this one setAdjustViewBounds(true);
this coding show the good quality and proper size image